# On Linux how can I enable HW timestamping for every packet on an interface?

Tags: linux, networking

I would like to enable hardware timestaming for all traffic in and out of an interface. The NIC is a SolarFlare SFN7322F. The idea is to use the HW stamps in the traffic to compute end to end latencies in some of the apps running in the box. What is the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: Duplicate on [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353037/on-linux-how-can-i-enable-hw-timestamping-for-every-packet-on-an-interface). Please don't ask identical questions on different stackexchanges, it will make find pertinent answers later difficult for other people. As this is for Linux, I'd suggest to delete this question on *superuser*.